# Show POST date in post preview

Tags: php, wordpress, date, post, preview

i'm using 'get_post_date() to show the date in every post preview in my home page. My only problem is that this comand returns me the pubblication date of the page and not of the pubblication date of the post. I tried the same comand in the post page and the result is correct.
How can I do to display the right date?

```
<?php
$block = $block_data[0];
$settings = $block_data[1];
?>
<?php if($block === 'title'): ?>

<div class="blocchetto"></div>
<div style="font-family: 'Prata',serif;font-size: 12px; margin-bottom:2px">
<?php echo get_the_date("d.m.Y",$post->ID); ?> </div>
<h2 class="post-title">
    <?php echo !empty($settings[0]) && $settings[0]!='no_link' ? $this->getLinked($post, $post->title, $settings[0], 'link_title') : $post->title ?>
</h2>

<?php elseif($block === 'image' && !empty($post->thumbnail)): ?>

<div class="post-thumb">
    <?php echo !empty($settings[0]) && $settings[0]!='no_link' ? $this->getLinked($post, $post->thumbnail, $settings[0], 'link_image') : $post->thumbnail ?>
</div>

<?php elseif($block === 'text'): ?>

<div class="entry-content">
    <?php echo !empty($settings[0]) && $settings[0]==='text' ?  $post->content : $post->excerpt; ?>
</div>
<?php elseif($block === 'link'): ?>

<div>
<a href="<?php echo $post->link ?>" id="vc_read_more" class="vc_read_more" title="<?php echo esc_attr(sprintf(__( 'Permalink to %s', "js_composer" ), $post->title_attribute)); ?>"<?php echo $this->link_target ?>><?php _e('Read more...', "js_composer") ?></a>



</div>



<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: since when does `get_the_date` expect two parameters? -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date#Parameters

Answer (score 0):

**Get date using this one**

```
<?php echo $post->post_date; ?>

    WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 1
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2014-05-31 10:11:20
        [post_date_gmt] => 2014-05-31 10:11:20
        [post_content] => Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!dsadadsdasdasdsdadasdsadasdasdarvi
        [post_title] => Hello world! 
        [post_excerpt] => this is a excerpt.ravi
        [post_status] => future
        [comment_status] => open
        [ping_status] => open
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => hello-world
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2014-05-08 11:56:31
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2014-05-08 11:56:31
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http://192.168.1.11/soci39/?p=1
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => post
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 1
        [filter] => raw
    )
```

Comment: I have to change this <?php echo get_the_date("d.m.Y",$post->ID); ?> with this <?php echo $post->post_date; ?>, is correct? because it doesn't work, the date disappeard

Comment: However thank you for the Wp_post object list is really useful!

Comment: Now I tried it in a normal post page and it works -.- but in the page i've posted before it doesn't work